# Cannot load Ubuntu image in VirtualPC in Windows 7

Tags: installation, windows-7, virtualization

I downloaded Ubuntu 32bit and when I open it in a virtual PC, it closes automatically.

No choice to install in safe mode. I removed `quiet` and `splash` and added `single` but then it also closes automatically.

How can I fix it so I can use Ubuntu in a Virtual PC?

Comment: That is not a question. If you wish to file a bug, then you should do that on launchpad.net.

Comment: this is a question, i ask whether anyone can install ubuntu in virtual pc

Comment: Then where is the question mark behind the question? :=)

Comment: @種瓜得瓜種豆得豆 - what version of ubuntu are you installing?  Please can you add to your question what settings you have used in Virtual PC - e.g. disk size, memory, networking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu runs nicely in all kinds of virtualization tools. If VirtualPC doesn't work, then you should contact Microsoft. This site supports Ubuntu, not Windows. You should probably try VirtualBox instead.

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question, at least for my purposes over here:

[Ubuntu on Microsoft Virtual PC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6361/ubuntu-on-microsoft-virtual-pc/210202#210202)

tl;dr - it is possible, with caveats.