# What to do to install Ubuntu 12.10 in Virtual PC?

Tags: installation, boot, virtualization, iso

After starting the VPC with the ISO captured it gets to the loading screen, everything seems ok and then the loading screen turns green. That is, after some seconds it changes to a screen covered by green ||||||| on the bottom 3/4 parts of the screen and the top is purple that turns black.

Nothing more happens after that.

I had waited for 10 min, tried the x64 bit (not compatible) and other irrelevant, ineffective things. What should I do?

VPC ram: 1111 MB, hard drive dynamic up to 130,000 MB, ISO image re-downloaded twice. The *host* OS is Windows 7.

Comment: Similar or same question as this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6361/ubuntu-on-microsoft-virtual-pc  - best advice is to avoid Virtual PC.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to start Ubuntu with basic graphics.
Immediately when the Virtual PC boots, hold down 'SHIFT' and you will go to the (hidden) GRUB2 menu, then press 'e' for the default (selected) option. Then add 'nomodeset' at the end of the the line starting with 'linux'

example:

```
linux   /vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-generic root=/dev/mapper/linux-root ro single nomodeset
```

then press the keyboard shortcut to boot (CTRL + x)

Comment: For `nomodeset` boot option see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/134029/cant-install-ubuntu-since-10-10

Answer (score 1):

As you start your computer, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>. When the GRUB boot menu appears, press <kbd>F6</kbd> for *Advanced* and select `nomodeset` by with the arrow keys. Press <kbd>enter</kbd> and then <kbd>escape</kbd> to get out of the submenu.

You can then install Ubuntu successfully. (This is somewhat similar to, but somewhat easier than, [Ronnie's method](https://askubuntu.com/a/208028/22949).)