# How to install Ubuntu in Microsoft Virtual PC?

Tags: installation, virtualization

I tried to install on a virtual PC, but I get a message that says the kernel requires and x86-64 CPU. It states that it detected an i686 CPU. The host machine is an AMD Phenom II x4 955.

Host OS: Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit

Visualization software: Microsoft Virtual PC Version 6.0.156.0

Guest OS: ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64

Comment: Host OS? Virtualisation software? Guest OS version? Settings? Please [edit] your question to add these details.

Comment: Edited to include above questions. Not sure what you mean by settings.

Comment: possible duplicated http://askubuntu.com/q/6361/169736

Comment: I'm a big fan of virtualbox myself....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the googling I have done it would appear that Microsoft Virtual PC does not support 64-bit guests. Google: "64bit guest windows virtual machine".

Try using a different virtualization software such as [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/).

Comment: I am running version 6.0.156.0 on the virtual machine. I Googled to seed if this version was compatible, but I'm beginning to think you're correct. I'll mark this as the answer as soon as I do some more research.